# Como ordenar un data frame en base a una variable con formato YYYY-SEMANA

Tags: r

Hola muy buenas a toda la comunidad, quisiera saber como puedo ordenar un data frame, en base a una variable que contendrá la concatenación de un año y una semana, a continuación pondré un mini ejemplo que invente para que se entienda el problema:

```
library(dplyr)
Año = c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001,2001,2001)
Sem = c(1, 10, 9, 8, 11, 6, 13, 1)

Data = data.frame(Año, Sem)
Data = Data %>% mutate(Año_Sem = paste0(Año, "-", Sem))
Data

 Año Sem Año_Sem
 2000   1  2000-1
 2000  10 2000-10
 2000   9  2000-9
 2000   8  2000-8
 2000  11 2000-11
 2001   6  2001-6
 2001  13 2001-13
 2001   1  2001-1
```

Me gustaría obtener lo siguiente:

```
Año Sem Año_Sem
2000   1  2000-1
2000   8  2000-8
2000   9  2000-9
2000  10 2000-10
2000  11 2000-11
2001   6  2001-1
2001  13 2001-6
2001   1  2001-13
```

Es decir, que la manera de ordenar sea en base al año (primeros 4 dígitos) y luego lo que viene después del guion, problema que no he podido resolver usando las funciones arrenge, sort y order,
ya que estas me ordenan en base al primer digito después del guion.

Comment: ¿Por que ordenar por la concatenación si puedes ordenar directamente por `Año` y `Sem`? Además, como tienes concatenado los datos jamás podrás ordenarlos de forma apropiada, la semana 10 siempre aparecerá antes de la 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar al funcción `arrange` de `dplyr`

```r
Data %>% arrange(Año, Sem)
```

`arrange` ordena las filas en base a las columnas desigandas. Para este caso ordena primero de acuerdo a la columna `Año` y `Sem`. Si se usa la columna `Año_sem` para ordenar, dado que es un dato tipo `character`, coje el primer caracter para ordenar, haciendo que el ´10´ este siempre antes que el ´2´.

Comment: Para que tu respuesta sea útil explica como funciona la solución. Asi como está, nadie aprenderá nada ...